# TexStudio can't find pygmentize in Pop!_os

Tags: python, linux, latex, tex-live, texstudio

I'm using Texstudio 21.2.2022 and i can´t use minted package

I have installed pygments with `pip install Pygments` and the terminal says `Requirement already satisfied: Pygments in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.7.1)` and put `-shell-escape` in the commands for lualatex

but texstudio displays the error `Package minted Error: You must have pygmentize' installed to use this package. \begin{document}`

In the messages it also displays `which: no pygmentize in (/usr/bin:/app/bin:/app/texlive/bin:/app/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux:/app/texlive/bin/aarch64-linux:/bin/:/usr/bin/:/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy/:/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/Versions/2.7/bin/)`

My operative system is Pop!_os 21.10

The python version i have is `Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 10 2021, 14:59:43)  [GCC 11.2.0] on linux`

Here is the log file:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (TeX Live 2021 - Flatpak)  (format=lualatex 2022.2.5)  21 FEB 2022 19:44
 system commands enabled.
**Minted.tex
(./Minted.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
Lua module: luaotfload 2021-01-08 3.17 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2020-12-30 2.73 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-12-30 2.73 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/albertohdez/.texlive2021/texm
f-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2021-01-07.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2021-01-07.
lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 0x1.8e76c8b439581p+1
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/albertohdez/.texlive2021/texm
f-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filt
er'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/albertohdez/.texlive2021
/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count175
\c@section=\count176
\c@subsection=\count177
\c@subsubsection=\count178
\c@paragraph=\count179
\c@subparagraph=\count180
\c@figure=\count181
\c@table=\count182
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
Package: minted 2017/07/19 v2.5 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
Package: fvextra 2019/02/04 v1.4 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count183
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2021/01/20 v3.7 verbatim text (tvz,hv)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count184
\FV@InFile=\read2
\FV@TabBox=\box47
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count185
\FV@StepNumber=\count186
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
))
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count187
\output=\toks16
\linenoprevgraf=\count188
\linenumbersep=\dimen139
\linenumberwidth=\dimen140
\c@linenumber=\count189
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count190
\c@LN@truepage=\count191
\c@internallinenumber=\count192
\c@internallinenumbers=\count193
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen141
\bframerule=\dimen142
\bframesep=\dimen143
\bframebox=\box48
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
\c@FV@TrueTabGroupLevel=\count194
\c@FV@TrueTabCounter=\count195
\FV@TabBox@Group=\box49
\FV@TmpLength=\skip49
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStart=\count196
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStop=\count197
\FV@LoopCount=\count198
\FV@NCharsBox=\box50
\FV@BreakIndent=\dimen144
\FV@BreakIndentNChars=\count199
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeft=\dimen145
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeftNChars=\count266
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRight=\dimen146
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRightNChars=\count267
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft=\dimen147
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeftNChars=\count268
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRight=\dimen148
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRightNChars=\count269
\c@FancyVerbLineBreakLast=\count270
\FV@LineBox=\box51
\FV@LineIndentBox=\box52
\FV@LineWidth=\dimen149
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count271
\calc@Bcount=\count272
\calc@Adimen=\dimen150
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen151
\calc@Askip=\skip50
\calc@Bskip=\skip51
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count273
\calc@Cskip=\skip52
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks17
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
runsystem(uname -s > "Minted.w18")...executed
 (./Minted.w18)
runsystem(rm -- "Minted.w18")...executed
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count274
\decimalpart=\count275
)
Package: xstring 2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip53
\fb@frw=\dimen152
\fb@frh=\dimen153
\FrameRule=\dimen154
\FrameSep=\dimen155
)
(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count276
\float@exts=\toks18
\float@box=\box53
\@float@everytoks=\toks19
\@floatcapt=\box54
)
\minted@appexistsfile=\read3
\minted@bgbox=\box55
\minted@code=\write4
\c@minted@FancyVerbLineTemp=\count277
\c@minted@pygmentizecounter=\count278
\@float@every@listing=\toks20
\c@listing=\count279
)
runsystem(mkdir -p _minted-Minted)...executed

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 225.

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for luatex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
runsystem(which pygmentize && touch Minted.aex)...failed 


! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this packag
e.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
Refer to the installation instructions in the minted documentation for more inf
ormation.

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count280
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box56
)
(./Minted.aux)
\openout1 = Minted.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3
.
 (/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

(/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count281
\scratchdimen=\dimen156
\scratchbox=\box57
\nofMPsegments=\count282
\nofMParguments=\count283
\everyMPshowfont=\toks21
\MPscratchCnt=\count284
\MPscratchDim=\dimen157
\MPnumerator=\count285
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count286
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks22
)
\openout3 = Minted.pyg
 (./_minted-Minted/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)
(./_minted-Minted/default.pygstyle)
runsystem(pygmentize -l c -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG -F tokenmerge -o _minted
-Minted/916909323916480C99F1AA97E621BB1565DDD462CAA3F940A8EDCA809F9FD16A.pygtex 
Minted.pyg)...failed 


! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9     \end{minted}
               
This could be caused by using -output-directory or -aux-directory 
without setting minted's outputdir, or by using a build tool that 
changes paths in ways minted cannot detect, 
or using frozencache with a missing file.

(./Minted.aux)
runsystem(rm Minted.pyg)...executed
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 5093 strings out of 478531
 100000,552014 words of node,token memory allocated
 426 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 6 attribute, 49 glue_spec,
 6 attribute_list, 2 write, 1 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 2:11,3:1,4:1,5:4,7:1,9:1
 24812 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 23 fonts using 2647927 bytes
 85i,1n,84p,267b,114s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.

PDF statistics: 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: Can you check in `Preferences->Build->Additional Search Paths->Commands` that it includes the same python version which you use in terminal? https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrJ13.png

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue on both my desktop and laptop, both running Pop!_OS 21.10.  I was able to fix this by reinstalling TeXstudio; specifically, I uninstalled the flatpak version of TeXstudio and reinstalled it from its ubuntu source.  After that, everything worked fine.  This is not the first time a flatpak implementation has had path problems in apps that I've installed.